# Can I install Python(x,y)2.7.10 if I have Python 3.6

Tags: python

I have Python 3.6 and I installed Python Python(x,y)2.7.10, but it does not work.

People told me that it can work, but I read on Stack Overflow that it cant work. 
Stack Overflow answer was more than 2 and a half years ago, so I wanted to check if something changed.

I installed Python(x,y)2.7.10, and I get the icon for it, but when I click it, nothing happens (nothing appears). Can you help me with this?

[image]

Comment: use anaconda to manage different version of python handily using virtualenvs (you can also set up virtualenvs manually but I'd highly recommend anaconda if there is nothing that clearly prohibits it).
See e.g. http://www.sexchrlab.org/blog/2015/10/26/managing-multiple-python-environments-using-anaconda

Comment: You can have multiple versions of python installed. Where did you read that it is impossible?